# Another "What Am I?" (intermediate)

Tags: riddle

> I can easily move from state to state, although, you won't find me in
>   Texas.
>
> I am very old, although I can be very young.
>
> Some people theorize my demise.
>
> Some people just want to save me.
>
> I don't like rock music, but I do have something in common with it.
>
> I am also a fan of exotic animals that you almost can't find anywhere
>   else.

### What am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Ice - Glacier

I can easily move from state to state, although, you won't find me in Texas.

> I see a little pun in 'state'. It seems like US states but I think it's about 3 states of the matter. Ice does move from state to state easily, it can be water & vapor with enough heat, and you don't see high masses of ice in Texas :)

I am very old, although I can be very young.

> Earth has had its poles for millenniums, but some of the glaciers could be formed newly, and thus are young

Some people theorize my demise.

> People try to understand why the poles of the Earth are losing their ice so rapidly, and each of them have different theories

Some people just want to save me.

> Foundations like Greenpeace

I don't like rock music, but I do have something in common with it.

> Icebergs I guess, big masses of ice just like a solid rock

I am also a fan of exotic animals that you almost can't find anywhere else.

> Well, you can't see penguins and polar bears out there so easily can you :)

Comment: Pretty sure this is thte correct answer!

Comment: Congrats, this is the correct answer! :)

Comment: Noice @Burak mete

Comment: I like the pun on "state" - clever :)

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> The Rocky Mountains?

I can easily move from state to state, although, you won't find me in Texas.

> These mountains span many states.

I am very old, although I can be very young.

> These mountains are constantly getting taller from tectonic plates shifting forming "new parts" of the mountain range.

Some people theorize my demise.

> [Here](https://www.quora.com/How-long-will-it-take-for-the-Rocky-Mountains-to-erode) people are theorizing how long it will take for these Rocky Mountains to erode/disappear.

Some people just want to save me.

> I'm not sure about this one, but maybe save the wildlife in the Rocky Mountains?

I don't like rock music, but I do have something in common with it.

> They both have the word *rock* in them

I am also a fan of exotic animals that you almost can't find anywhere else.

> There are a lot of exotic animals in the rocky mountains.

Pretty sure the above isn't right, but I'm just here to give it a shot! :D

Comment: Good guess, but incorrect!

Answer (score 3):

> Is it water? Easily changes from state to state: water changes from vapour to liquid very easily. Saving water. Home to exotic sea animals that you cant find anywhere else but in water.

Comment: There's no water in Texas? :)

Comment: @Jacob Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please be sure to add spoiler tags next time by putting >! In front of your texts. This time, I've already done it for you. ;)

Comment: Water is not correct, but you are guessing in the right direction!

Comment: I believe Texas is a home to about several hundred very beautiful lakes and also has a giant rivrer rinning through it

Answer (score 3):

I think this question allows for too many valid answers, with not much to choose between them except arbitrary "This is the answer I was thinking of". For example:

I can easily move from state to state, although, you won't find me in Texas.

> Basque language

I am very old, although I can be very young.

> Language is old but can have very new words or new speakers.

Some people theorize my demise.

> Some linguists expect the Internet to cause languages to gravitate to a very few 'survivors' over time.

Some people just want to save me.

> Nationals and fans of the language, and separatists.

I don't like rock music, but I do have something in common with it.

> Nobody seems to have an issue with icebergs and rainforests "not liking rock music", so Ill skip this and find some commonality. The basque language is sometimes used musically and with violence as well, like rock music.

I am also a fan of exotic animals that you almost can't find anywhere else.

> Words can be pretty exotic creatures and Basque words are often not seen "almost anywhere else".

Answer (score 2):

> Rainforest

I can easily move from state to state, although, you won't find me in Texas.

> Forests don't care about borders, though no rainforest in Texas

I am very old, although I can be very young.

> Some rainforests are thousands of years old, though can have new growth

Some people theorize my demise.

> Any climate scientist

Some people just want to save me.

> Greenpeace

I don't like rock music, but I do have something in common with it.

> Rainforests are pretty loud with all the animals/bugs

I am also a fan of exotic animals that you almost can't find anywhere else.

> Many exotic species are unique to rainforests

Comment: Good guess, but not correct!

Answer (score 1):

Another example answer (question is just *too* open to multiple answers):

I can easily move from state to state, although, you won't find me in Texas.

> Coral - easily moves from nonexistent to living to dead states based on climate; easily taken from country (state) to country as souvenirs or mementos. Not typically found in Texas

I am very old, although I can be very young.

> Coral reefs are very old but individual polyps are very young.

Some people theorize my demise.

> Climate. Widely predicted.

Some people just want to save me.

> Environmemtalists and many members of the public.

I don't like rock music, but I do have something in common with it.

> Coral reefs are very similar to rock, also carbonate based.

I am also a fan of exotic animals that you almost can't find anywhere else.

> Coral ecosystem is immensely diverse specialised and virtually unique, many creatures are exotic and not found elsewhere.